# Rollup 3 For Exchange Server 2007 KB979784 Issues?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, update

Rollup 3 For Exchange Server 2007 KB979784 Issues?

Is this update safe to run on servers? / Has anyone had any issues with this Update
KB979784??

Answer (score 0):

I had no problems when previously running this update, however as with all updates, that's not to say you won't have any. You should be prepared for the worst and have full backups and a disaster recovery plan.